# Real time map matching

Tags: real-time, osrm, map-matching

Есть мобильное приложение трекер(просто отправляет координаты местоположения на сервер). Есть сервер который сохраняет и отправляет по вебсокету на веб приложение(клиент) координаты. Какие есть способы сделать сопоставление с картой в режиме реального времени. Чтобы на клиент отправлять уже сопоставленные с картой данные? Как в яндекс доставке

Я использовал valhalla engine, отправлял на адрес /locate
{
"locations": [{"lat": %f, "lon": %f, "radius": 1, "search_cutoff": 10}],
"costing": "auto"
},
вроде работало неплохо, но были неточности на перекрестках, точка сопоставлялась с другой дорогой или если gps сигнал совсем плохой(человек шел по тротуару, а точка сопоставлялась с дорогой). Так я пришел к выводу, что адрес /locate не стоит использовать. Я думаю нужно  как-то учитывать предыдущие значения